# IntelliJ - Problem connecting to PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, intellij-idea

I am new to PostgreSQL (I normally use other database engines), and I also do not use Java often.

My Problem is that I get the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for DATABASE_NAME
 java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at
 java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
```

I followed this tutorial: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-jdbc/connecting-to-postgresql-database/ and added postgresql-42.2.5.jar as a library.

[image]

The problem is that adding the driver as a library, as can be seen in the screenshot, has no effect.

So my question is: how do I connect to a PostgreSQL database using Java and the latest IntelliJ?

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE 1:
[image]

UPDATE 2:
Since the code has been requested: I have replaced the original code by a minimal code that will cause the error:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class IngestData
{
    protected static String url;
    protected static final String user = "user";
    protected static final String password = "password";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Connection connection = null;
        url = args[args.length-1];
        try
        {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println("SUCCESS");

        } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The console output is:

```
ERROR
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for http://127.0.0.1:10282/db01617792
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at IngestData.main(IngestData.java:17)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is the link to the git repository containing the code:
https://github.com/ka6555/StackOverflow-Postgresql-Problem.git

UPDATE 3:
I found the error:

I need to change

```
protected static String url;
```

to

```
protected static String url = "jdbc:postgresql://";
```

and

```
url = args[args.length-1];
```

to

```
url += args[args.length-1];
```

While this solves my original problem, the program is now stuck executing the following line:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

There is no error but the program will simply run like with an endless loop never going beyond this code line.

UPDATE 4:
I have fixed all problems now.

Comment: Did you add this library to the module dependencies? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies.

Comment: No, I hadn't. But adding it does not seem to make a difference. I added a screenshot in an update.

Comment: Are you configuring/building your project with a tool such as Maven or Gradle?

Comment: No. I am simply using a plain Java project. All I am trying to do is read some data from some files and put it into the database. That's probably one class since the files are already structured.

Comment: @Willi Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was that I used a command line parameter as the database url without prefixing it with **`jdbc:postgresql://`**. Additionally, I had to reinstall postgresql because of some odd behavior I could not figure out the reason for.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are missing the postgres jar file in your project dependencies.

- Open the Project Structure (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S on Windows)
- Select modules / dependencies tab
- You should see something like the following:

[image]

If the postgres dependency is missing:

- Klick on the + sign on the right side of the screenshot
- Choose Library/Project Library and your postgres jar file

Your code should now run. Let me know if it helps.

**Note**: Please provide your minmal working code on GitHub for a quicker response.

Comment: I added the code to both my question and a git repository whose link is provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the message you get when the URL syntax is incorrect.

[This](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html) is the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was using statis IP address, which prevented to access some url.
Changing to automatic IP assign fixed it.
[image]